# Facebook app deleted all pictures

Tags: facebook, images

For years I uploaded all my pictures to Facebook via the Speedy Uploader app for Android. As of yesterday, all my pictures are gone since the original owner of the Facebook app deleted it from the Facebook App Store. Now all pictures of all users that uploaded pictures to Facebook via this app are lost!

The new owner of the app doesn’t know if he will get the rights to the Facebook app and Facebook hasn’t answered to several emails.

What can I do to get my pictures back?

Comment: Thank u, but this will be helpful for the future,  any idea how to get my pics back right now? I see theyre still stored as they get counted in the albums but I cant see them :( and Facebook doesnt respond, I sent so many requests since yesterday :(

Answer (score 1):

I emailed the Speedy Uploader team and got no reply.
They did not reply on Facebook either. 
The pix are gone unless the makers or new owners get the app and past storage servers up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

I am very sorry to say this, but there is nothing that you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have taken them by now, right?

The photos are stored on Facebook and not on the application that uploads them and therefor you should be able to see them and get them if you access Facebook through facebook.com.